# Mailto or hyperlink doesn't work on footer menu due to submenu script

Tags: javascript, onclick, footer, submenu, mailto

Do to my submenu script my mailto link or any hyperlink doesn't work and i don't why and where in the script it causes problems.

```
$(function () {
$('footer > ul > li a').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();
    var $parentli = $(this).closest('li');
    $parentli.siblings('li').find('ul:visible').hide();
    $parentli.find('> ul').stop().toggle();
});
});

$(document).click(function() {
$("footer ul li ul").hide();
});
```

[Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/foroloca/65t6gk5n/](http://jsfiddle.net/foroloca/65t6gk5n/)

Answer (score 0):

You're calling `event.preventDefault();`. This prevents the default functionality of the event, and ultimately prevents your link from being fired.

If you need this functionality in place for the other `a` elements in your footer, I suggest you add a class name specifically to those and modify your event handler to only apply to those elements:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <a href="..." class="prevent-default">...</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="mailto:...">...</a>
    </li>
    ...
</ul>
```

```js
$('footer > ul > li a.prevent-default').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    ...
});
```

[**JSFiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/65t6gk5n/4/).

Comment: thank you for helping, but what the submenu doesn't work now and when clicking the scrollbar jumps to top again.

Comment: @foroloca have you definitely added the class name to the correct elements and modified your JavaScript like I've specified in my answer?

Comment: yes but also the fiddle example the submenu doesn't open. The top and info menu button work fine with the beginning script, the only problem is when i use a mailto/hyperlink on the MAIL button. I understand thats because the event.preventDefault(); but i need that for preventing jumping to top. The TOP button is differently scripted but again that works fine. Again thank you

Comment: @foroloca that's because I'd forgotten to add the `prevent-default` class to it. Please see this updated JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/65t6gk5n/4/ which I've now edited into my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use selector by href.

```
$('footer > ul > li a[href="#"]')
```

And all hyperlinks with hash in href (href="#") will fire with your onclick handler

```
http://jsfiddle.net/65t6gk5n/3/
```

Comment: thank you for helping, but is there way so you don't need a extra class and it will also will function for hyperlinks?

Comment: You can use selector by href.
$('footer > ul > li a[href="#"]')
And all hyperlinks with hash in href (href="#") will fire with your onclick handler

http://jsfiddle.net/65t6gk5n/3/

Comment: Yes thats what i need! Oops that was quite simple ;-) Thank you!